# MapThread Not Mapping on Ragged Array

Tags: list-manipulation, map

**Update:** *WRI Support has considered this a missing feature of `MapThread` instead of a bug.  A request to update `MapThread` to support ragged arrays has been logged.*

---

`MapThread` is not mapping over ragged arrays.  It is my expectation that it should map given `Map`'s behavior on ragged arrays and no information to the contrary in `MapThread`'s documentation.

`Map` works fine on ragged array.

```
Map[f, Range@Range@3, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{f[1]}, {f[1], f[2]}, {f[1], f[2], f[3]}}
> ```

But `MapThread` has issues.

```
MapThread[f, 
 {
  Range@Range@3,
  Range@Range@3
  },
 2]
```

> `MapThread::mptd: Object {{1},{1,2},{1,2,3}} at position {2, 1} in MapThread[f,{{{1},{1,2},{1,2,3}},{{1},{1,2},{1,2,3}}},2] has only 1 of required 2 dimensions.`

It is complaining about missing dimensions but the two lists are identical.  My real problem has over 2 million rows and `MapIndex` is slower than `MapThread`.

I think this is a bug. Yes/No?

Win 10 Ent with Mma 11.2

---

A representative sample of data as requested.

```
SeedRandom[1122]
raggedDims = RandomInteger[{10, 22}, 150000];
assoc1 = TakeList[
   AssociationThread[{"z"}, #] & /@ 
    RandomReal[{0., 10.}, {Total@raggedDims, 1}], raggedDims];
assoc2 = TakeList[
   AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c"}, #] & /@ 
    RandomReal[{0., 10.}, {Total@raggedDims, 3}], raggedDims];
```

and I was trying to do the below and assign it back to another association with `Part`. Where `data` is a list of associations.

```
data[[All, "key"]] = 
    MapThread[
      Association,
      {
       assoc1,
       assoc2
       },
      2];
```

Comment: Not pretty ... `MapThread[MapThread[f, {##}] &, {Range@Range[3], Range@Range[3]}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Nice workaround. Would you agree it is bug-like.  Thinking of reporting to WRI.

Comment: @Szabolcs  Well, starts to be an issue with `Range@Range@Range@3`. I suppose `Nest` can be used to generalize the nested `MapThread`s.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a bug, rather a missing feature.  Could you show a few benchmark datasets (with depths and lengths relevant to your actual problem, so that the method can be tailored to it)?

Comment: Also not pretty: `MapThread[Thread@*f, {Range@Range@3, Range@Range@3}, 1]`

Comment: @C.E. They are list of the same length. There are two arguments and they are identical in all lengths.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### A quick note about the problem:

While I was trying to write a generalization to my `Flatten+Apply` approach I faced a problem that I need to now the `Depth[array]`. Which makes it problematic for e.g. `test = {#, Sin@#} &@Range@Range@` because symbolic `Sin[1]` adds to the depth even though you would not care.

So now you have uneven, with respect to depth, arrays. And `ArrayDepth` won't help you as it can't deal with ragged arrays.

Maybe that's it, I don't know. Anyway

#### Specific solution:

```
test = {#, Sin@N@#} &@Range@Range@3
```

```
Apply[
 foo,
 Flatten[test, {{2}, {3}, {1}}],
 {2}
]
```

> ```
> {{foo[1, 1]}, {foo[1, 1], foo[2, 2]}, {foo[1, 1], foo[2, 2],   foo[3, 3]}}
> ```

#### General(?) solution

I'm not 100% sure but this looks like a generalization:

```
test = {#, Sin@N@#} &@Range@Range@Range@3;

MapThreadRagged[f_, arr_List, lvl_Integer
]:= MapThreadRagged[f, arr, lvl, Depth[arr]]

MapThreadRagged[f_, arr_List, lvl_Integer, depth_Integer] := Module[{spec}
  , spec = RotateRight[List /@ Range[depth - 1], lvl];
  Apply[f, Flatten[arr, spec], {lvl}]
  ]


MapThreadRagged[foo, test, 3] // MatrixForm
MapThreadRagged[foo, test, 2] // MatrixForm
MapThreadRagged[foo, test, 1] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

and to workaround a problem mentioned in the first paragraph:

```
test = {#, Sin@#} &@Range@Range@Range@3;
```

you can provide the depth by yourself:

```
MapThreadRagged[foo, test, 3, 5] // MatrixForm
MapThreadRagged[foo, test, 2, 5] // MatrixForm
MapThreadRagged[foo, test, 1, 5] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: I like this one :)

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch thanks, I like to force myself to do something with generalized `Flatten` from time to time to stay in shape :p

Answer (score 6):

Two more workarounds:

```
lists = {Range@Range@3, Range@Range@3};

MapThread[f, #] & /@ Transpose[lists]

Thread[g[f, Transpose[lists]]] /. g -> MapThread
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not just pad the list and create an extra definition for `f`?

```
f[0, 0] = Nothing;
MapThread[f, {PadRight@Range@Range@3, PadRight@Range@Range@3}, 2]

(* {{f[1, 1]}, {f[1, 1], f[2, 2]}, {f[1, 1], f[2, 2], f[3, 3]}} *)
```

or in case `f[0,0]` is required to do something then this:

```
f[Missing[], Missing[]] = Nothing;
MapThread[f, {PadRight[Range@Range@3, {3, 3}, Missing[]], PadRight[Range@Range@3, {3, 3}, Missing[]]}, 2]

(* {{f[1, 1]}, {f[1, 1], f[2, 2]}, {f[1, 1], f[2, 2], f[3, 3]}} *)
```